# Loading image without using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

How to include loader image without usng AJAX controls like Scriptmanager, UpdateProgerss.

Note: Page Getting Load.

Geetha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just put an Ajax style loader image on your page then goto [this website](http://www.ajaxload.info/) and generate one.  Then simply place that on your page where you need it

Comment: That's a great resource that I'd nearly forgotten about.

Comment: I want to display this image during page load time. Once page is ready it should no display

Comment: you could always do... `$(function() { $("#myLoadingImage").hide(); });`. Then your loading image would have the id `myLoadingImage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="myloadingimage.gif" alt="Loading!" />
```

:-)

Comment: "On that topic, do not act as though alt texts function as placeholders while graphics load; do not, in other words, use alt="Loading image" or anything similar. Nor should you fill an alt text with advertising slogans of any kind." - http://joeclark.org/book/sashay/serialization/Chapter06.html